# Not able to convert `executions` property of maven in sbt

Tags: maven, sbt, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have a scenario to run `jmeter-script` using `sbt`. I am able to run jmeter-script using `maven install` with below pom.xml:-

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have converted plugin part in sbt

```
"com.lazerycode.jmeter" % "jmeter-maven-plugin" % "1.4.1"
```

But not able to convert `executions` part in sbt.

Can anyone help me to convert this `executions` part?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Comment: Also you are using a massively out of date version of the plugin, that latest is 1.10.1(2.0.0 in the near future)